# How many open CLI terminals is "normal" for a workflow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, gulp

So after tinkering around with Gulp/Bower/ExpressJS/Jade for a while I settled on a workflow that I'd like to switch to.  The possible issue I still have yet to solve is, I have to have two terminals open at the same time to use this workflow.  One to fire up Gulp and the other to fire up ExpressJS by calling `nodemon index.js`.  I'm still a bit naive when it comes to Node.js/CLI stuff so I don't know if this situation happens on a regular basis or not and would appreciate some advice.  Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Gulp/Grunt/Bower/Npm and that kind of applications, in my opinion it is normal to have more than 1 CLI terminal open.

Personally I have always 2 or 3 CLI terminals open:

- One for watching the files and building the application
- One for watching the files and testing (code coverage, unit tests etc.)
- Optionally one for running on separate devices (when using Cordova)

You could create a script file (.bat or something like that) to start the CLI terminals for you, this could save some time of course.

Answer (score 1):

We're currently developing an app that has 4 layers: an API server, a worker server, a static user interface and a iOS app. Thus, I'm always having at least 4 terminals open: 2 for nodemon (API and worker), one for grunt (static UI) and another grunt for the iOS app. I'd say there's no limit to the number of processes you need.
In addition, I have terminal windows open for me to type commands (e.g. git).

Anyway, it could help you to expand the use of Gulp. For example, you could integrate nodemon into gulp: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon